# Azure DevOps REST API - How to Calculate "Lead Time To Change"

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using Azure DevOps and would like to get information on our Lead Time To Change (time taken from code change to deployment to production).

I can do this in the browser as our Work Items have PRs and Deployments associated with them. How do I do this via the REST API?

Using the REST API I have found queries to get "completed PRs" and for one of those "Associated Work Items". But from there, I can't see a way of get associated deployments.

Is that possible? Or do I need to go another route?